# Is there any difference between "center_horizontal|center_vertical" and "center"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to center an image in a linearLayout.

Is there any difference between

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

and

```
android:gravity="center"
```

?

Comment: Are you using imageview inside linear layout?

Comment: yes. Why? how does this matter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no difference. According to source code

```
public static final int CENTER = CENTER_VERTICAL|CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```

Comment: How can I find this for next time?

Comment: You can check `Gravity` class.

Answer (score 3):

There really is not difference between the two except that it's less code using `center`. combining `center_horizontal` and `center_veritcal` is the equivalent of `center`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question but i want just want to share to anyone what i found. And pardon the bad english.

Imagine Horizontal line as X an vertical line as Y (like the one used in 3d modeling model ex: maya and 3dmax).

[image]
<sub>(source: [helpingwithmath.com](http://www.helpingwithmath.com/printables/worksheets/geometry/grid0_10.gif))</sub>

center_horizontal = this one will put your view/layout postion of X into zero

center_vertical = as you guess, it will make the postion Y into zero

center = this one will make the position X and Y into Zero

I figured this out by my own when trying all of them on my layout. Cant give an example because my printscreen isnt working.

I dont know if there is a documentation that tell you about this, so correct me if im wrong. I just hope it will help someone understand :cheers.