# Android: Layout gravity

Tags: android-layout

Can someone help me understand what do `centre_horizontal` and `centre_vertical` mean in Layout gravity? I   am really unable to visualise how the widgets are positioned under the effect of those gravities. I try to imagine an X-Y plane, but can't make out where is the horizontal centre and where is the vertical centre. Some explanation (preferably using a graph) would help me a lot. 
Thanks!

Comment: You need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478953/8244632).

Comment: So it means the bottom left corner of my screen is the horizontal centre as well as vertical centre?

Answer (score 0):

@UserKunal123, there are two gravities we can set to UI component.
`layout_gravity` and `gravity`. LayoutGravity is used to position the UI component in the parent/root, whereas Gravity is used to position the content of the UI component within the component itself. 
E.g.
If we have a `LinearLayout` and we set `android:gravity="center_horizontal", the child views of the LinearLayout will be arranged center horizontally in it.

Now, if we don't want to set the `gravity` of the LinearLayout but instead want to set gravity of the child view, then we can do `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal` in the child view to align it center horizontal in the parent layout.

If we just have a `TextView` and we want the text to be centered within the TextView, we can do `android:gravity="center"` in the TextView and the text will be centered within the TextView.

Hope this helps.